# Uncaught TypeError: Property 'min' of object #<Object> is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui, knockout.js, slider

I'm trying to make use of the knockout slider binderhalders that RP Niemeyer has posted a few times. Unfortunately while trying to use it I receive the error within the title.

```
(function($){

ko.bindingHandlers.slider = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().sliderOptions || {};
        var sliderValues = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());

        if(sliderValues.min !== undefined) {
            options.range = true;
        }

        options.slide = function(e, ui) {
            if(sliderValues.min) {
                // Errors here
                sliderValues.min(ui.values[0]);
                sliderValues.max(ui.values[1]);
            } else {
                sliderValues.value(ui.value);
            }
        };

        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $(element).slider("destroy");
        });

        $(element).slider(options);
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var sliderValues = ko.toJS(valueAccessor());
        if(sliderValues.min !== undefined) {
            $(element).slider("values", [sliderValues.min, sliderValues.max]);
        } else {
            $(element).slider("value", sliderValues.value);
        }
    }
};

this.range = {
    'cook': function(kitchen, name, label, recipe){

        var food = new this.viewModel(kitchen);
        food.name = name;
        food.label = label;
        food.total(recipe.numberOfResults);
        food.criteriaMin = recipe.minValue;
        food.criteriaMax = recipe.maxValue;

        return food;
    },
    'viewModel': function(kitchen){
        var self = this;

        this.name = '';
        this.label = '';

        this.total = window.ko.observable();

        this.criteriaMin = ko.observable(0);
        this.criteriaMax = ko.observable(100);

        this.loading = window.ko.observable(false);
        this.template = '';

        this.getSelection = function(){
            return null;
        };

        this.setSelection = function(){

        };
    },
    'template': '<th class="idc-td-criteria" scope="row" data-bind="text:label"></th>' +
        '<td class="idc-td-value idc-td-slider">' +
        '   <label for="AmountMin"  class="hiddenText">Amount Min</label>' +
        '   <input type="text" data-default="0" data-maxdecimal="2" class="idc-textinput idc-sliderinput" maxlength="6" data-bind="value: criteriaMin || \'0.00\'">' +
        '   <span class="slider" data-bind="slider: { min: criteriaMin, max: criteriaMax }, sliderOptions: {min: 0, max: 100, step: 1}"></span>' +
        '   <label for="AmountMax"  class="hiddenText">Amount Max</label>' +
        '   <input type="text" data-default="10" data-maxdecimal="2" class="idc-textinput idc-sliderinput" maxlength="6" data-bind="value: criteriaMax || \'10.00\'">' +
        '</td>' +
        '<td class="idc-td-results" data-bind="text:total"></td>' +
        '<td class="idc-td-remove">' +
        '   <a href="#">' +
        '       <img src="images/column_delete.png" alt="Delete criteria [criteria name]" role="button"  />' +
        '   </a>' +
        '</td>'
    };
}).call(window.idmsScreener.chefs, jQuery);
```

I've tried to change it from sliderValues.min() to sliderValues.min = ui.values[0]; However by changing that I can't seem to get the values back correctly.  I also tried changing the min and max values of the slider options so that they are not statically set but that throws a completely different error.  Any help on solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can reproduce based on this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/PgGL4/

Comment: I was able to figure out my problem was that I was setting my viewmodel in the wrong way. Before I was doing `food.criteriaMin = recipe.minValue; food.criteriaMax = recipe.maxValue;` instead of `food.criteriaMin(recipe.minValue); food.criteriaMax(recipe.maxValue);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to resolve this.  Determined that I was setting my min and max criteria in correctly. I was doing assignment using an equals sign which was overriding the observable.